# Copy windows Default profile between servers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, profile

I seem to have accidentally deleted the C:\Users\Default folder which I think is causing new users not being able to log on. This is on a Server 2012 r2, is it safe to copy the Default folder from a server 2008 r2 to the 2012 r2 one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, got no quick response so I just went ahead and tried it and it seems to work ok. At least new users can log on now.

Comment: It would even be safe to copy it from Windows Vista, although some default settings could be different (not sure about XP and older, but probably same here). This compatibility is required for the domain *Default User* profile to work.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP profiles aren't compatible or interoperable with Windows Vista and above.